# GDAL raster merge not working

Tags: raster, gdal, merge

When trying to merge several raster files I get the message: /bin/sh: gdal_merge.py: command not found.  I am running QGIS version 3.2.0 on a Mac mini, Catalina 10.15.5. The raster files are geotif LIDAR files.

Comment: Do other GDAL processing alogs work? I would try warp as a test. Have you been able to run it in the past?

Comment: what does `locate gdal_merge.py` return?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I decided, in the end, to revert to the current stable version (3.10.7), and now the merge works fine.